# Menu css + javascript e jquery

Tags: javascript, css

Bom galera, estou precisando de criar uma forma para reconhecer em qual menu estou clicando, tenho minha index onde eu chamo meus menus com um include, portanto preciso colocar uma barra verde no bottom do menu que está clicado.

Como fazer isto ?

```
<ul class="mainnav">
  <li class="active"><a href="principal.php"><i class="icon-dashboard"></i><span>Início</span> </a> </li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <i class="icon-sort"></i><span>Cadastro</span> <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="listaUsuario.php">Usuários</a></li>
      <li><a href="listaPublicacao.php">Publicação</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Clientes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Paginas Internas</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="cadastroMenu.php"><i class="icon-th-list"></i><span>Menu</span> </a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-picture"></i><span>Banner</span> </a> </li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-book"></i><span>Contatos</span> </a> </li>
</ul>
```

Eu preciso apenas acrescentar `active` na classe do li que está em seleção. Um exemplo é

Conseguir fazer, porem ele ativa o Active na classe, mais fica pouco segundos voltando apenas para li marcada principal, o objetivo para iniciar a index como Active é para ela aparecer marcada assim que o site for iniciado, alguém tem alguma ideia melhor que solucione este problema.

```
$(function () {
    $('.mainnav li').on('click', function(){
        $(this).addClass('dropdown active');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');

    });
});
```

Comment: isso é um site?, você está usando algum *CMS* ou *framework* pra desenvolver?

Comment: utilize o seletor CSS `li:hover a`, tem uma resposta que pode ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/42669

Comment: @ErlonCharles sim é um framework

Comment: @Sanção não é desta forma, quero dinâmico.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, você quer que quando você estiver em uma página o link no meno referente a esta página já venha marcado é isso?

Comment: @ErlonCharles conseguir o Caio mostrou como fazer da forma correta, obrigado pela colaboração.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Talvez algo deste tipo seja o que você procura?

```js
$('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', function(){
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
li.active{
  color: green;
}

li{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT:**

Conforme conversamos nos comentários, e conforme a edição da sua pergunta (e, honestamente, conforme o *meu* entendimento dela), fiz um ajuste no código acima, pra chegar no resultado que acredito que você deseja. Pra não blotar a resposta, coloquei o código numa [pen](http://codepen.io/caio1511/pen/mJMjZj).

Considerações:

- Usei praticamente o mesmo **HTML** que você postou na sua pergunta. Retirei coisas como `<a>`s e `<i>`s pra deixar o código mais limpo.
- Usar o [`hover`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/42669), conforme citado pelo @Sanção nos comentários, me parece a coisa mais natural (e mais fácil de se fazer). Não sei se você tem algum impedimento com relação a isso.
- O código não considera (e isto também não entra no escopo da sua pergunta), como você vai fazer para abrir os seus *dropdowns*, tanto que você verá que a classe `active` continua presente no último elemento interno que você clicou, caso você clique em um elemento externo (não sei se você precisa tratar isso). Se sim, acredito que esse tratamento possa ser feito juntamente com a abertura dos referidos *dropdowns*.

O segredo pra resolver foi colocar os títulos dos itens no primeiro nível dentro de uma tag `<span>`. Assim, os seletores ficaram mais simples.

Comment: Porem quando está clicado no index não funciona.

Comment: Conseguir resolver, faltava colocar o index, como active, pois ele é o primeiro a ser selecionado.

Comment: Esse código funciona apenas para os `li` dentro de `.dropdown-menu`, Se você clicar em algum outro `li`, ele não vai funcionar mesmo.

Comment: `.removeClass('active')`? Se um dia o @RenanRodrigues colocar outra classe em algum item, ela vai pro espaço no dia que alguém clicar em algum item do menu.

Comment: Excelente, @ctgPi. editado.

Comment: E se caso eu tiver uma ul dentro do li, este itens como fica ?

Comment: @ctgPi Sabe como resolver o problema de quando vc clica em um li dentro de uma um diferente ele marca o index ?

Comment: Ok Obg, que Deus lhe abençoe!

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira conseguiu resolver ? porque agora na verdade ele não funciona, direitinho, devido ao index, eu preciso que ele comece com Active, preciso também quando ele clicar nos menus dropsdowns ele permaneça selecionado o li maior.

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira conseguiu mexer em algo ?

Comment: @RenanRodrigues veja minha resposta editada. qualquer coisa, só perguntar

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira infelizmente seu código ainda não está conseguindo obter o desejável. Quando eu clico em algum menu que tenha um link ele desabilita o Active e deixa apenas para o index. Se observar no site mesmo que me mandou ele não cumpri com os objetivos. Teria como dar mais uma olhada ?

Comment: @RenanRodrigues mas não é exatamente isso que você quer? que a classe `active` fique apenas no ícone que você clicou? Se não for, desconfio que não estou entendendo a sua pergunta. Se você puder explicar melhor, posso até tentar te ajudar

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira está acontecendo o seguinte, quando eu clico em algum menu que não tem o `href`, ele permanece clicado, porem quando eu clico em algum menu que tem um `href`, ele adiciona o `Active` e logo depois desabilita, não fica permanente, o ideal seria sair somente depois que eu mudar de pagina, ai sim ele iria para o `Active` da pagina em que eu estou em questão, da forma que está, ele fica apenas no index, ele vai para outra mais desabilita logo em seguida.

Comment: Ah. Você está mudando de página, certo? Quando você vai `listaUsuario.php`, por exemplo, ele carrega o menu com a classe `active`  no primeiro link,  é isso?

Comment: Exatamento @CaioFelipePereira quando clico em qualquer link ele volta para primeira.

Comment: Então o problema é diferente. Você tem que atribuir a classe `active` de acordo com a página que você se encontra. Se o seu menu, estaticamente, tem a classe no `index`, ele vai ser recriado toda vez que você muda de página e, assim, voltar a classe pro index. Você pode criar um menu diferente para cada página, no seu php, de acordo com o ícone que tem que estar ativo, ou salvar o ultimo elemento que vc clicou em um cookie ou algum tipo de storage, e atribuir a classe a partir daí. Mas dessa maneira o problema se tornou outro....